# Catch 'cannot stat : No such file or directory' error in Ruby

Tags: ruby, exception

I am copying a file from one directory to other using /bin/cp/. If the file does not exists in the source directory the compiler throws this error:

> /bin/cp: cannot stat `path/to/file': No such file or directory

I want to catch this error so that I can display my error message.

```
begin
  `/bin/cp /path/to/file /current/directory/`   
rescue
  print("File was not found")   
  exit 1;
end
```

But the control never goes to rescue. It still prints out the error mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main error is you are doing a system call and system call are not going to give you an exception when it fails.

So you can do this

```
#!/bin/env ruby

require 'fileutils'

begin
  FileUtils.cp '/path/to/file', '/current/directory/'
rescue Errno::ENOENT
  print('File was not found')
  exit 1
end
```

Obviously you can rescue all exception but is a good practice to say what you error you want to manage.

if you still trying to do it with system call you can do something like this

```
#!/bin/env ruby

unless system('/bin/cp /path/to/file /current/directory/ 2> /dev/null')
  puts 'my custom error'
  exit(1)
end
```

but is pretty ugly and you loose control if you want to manage many errors (like no space left)